# variable variables for optimizer routine

Tags: python, function, variables, python-2.7, dictionary

How to create an objective function with variable variables?

I am trying to optimize a certain function with many variables, all with different degrees of uncertainty.

```
result = opt.minimize(fObj,x0,method='nelder-mead',
            options={'xtol':1e-1})
```

fObj has many variables, say a, b, c, d, e, f, g, etc. However due to the information in my objective function it only makes sense to optimize for 3 variables at the same time. So I want to play around by varying say a,c, and d and maybe next a, d, and f..

I want to make a function where I can have only two inputs:

1. variables to optimize (array of 3 strings?)
2. Their starting values

The option I was thinking off is to feed fObj the default values for all my variables through globals and include a global string with variable names to replace with the exec() function.

```
def fObj(x):
    global a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, VarList

    # some hocus pocus that reads VarList
    # e.g.
    # VarList = ['c', 'd', 'f']
    # c = x[0]
    # d = x[0]
    # f = x[0]

    return someMathematiclOutputInvolvingAllVars
```

What is the best / most pythonic way to achieve this goal?

Comment: For starters, using `exec` is probably never the best or most pythonic way for doing anything, ever.

Comment: so how did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1):

If a, b, c ... are floats for instance I would use a float container :

```
class MyFloat:
  self.val
  ...

a = MyFloat(0.1)
...
def fObj():
  global a, b
  use a.val, b.val, ... instead of a, b, ...
```

the opt.min function is given the array of variables to minimize on (A, C, D) and it can change their value without knowing what their name is

This is not very pythonic but I think it is still simple enough for your complex problem :)